# How to add a drop shadow to a ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Is there's a way I can add a drop shadow to a ListView item in C# (`view = LargeIcon` mode) without using a third party component?

The only way I can think of is by drawing the drop shadow on the image itself, but this way when I click on the image, the drop shadow will also be highlighted (because it is part of the image!). So maybe there is a way to make the ListView only highlight a specific area of the image when I click on an item?

Comment: I'm guessing it's possible with a custom draw method, but I have no experience in this myself. Try doing a Google search for "ListView.DrawItem".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a suitable dropshadow bitmap and use `OwnerDrawing` the `ListView` items.

Here is an example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    shadow = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(aDropShadowBitmap);
    overlay = new Bitmap(64, 64);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(overlay))
            G.Clear(Color.FromArgb(127, 31, 191, 255));
}

Bitmap shadow;
Bitmap overlay;

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = e.Item;
    Point bLoc = new Point(e.Bounds.X + 35, e.Bounds.Y + 10);
    Size imgS = imageList1.ImageSize;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(shadow, bLoc);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[e.ItemIndex], bLoc);

    if ((e.State & ListViewItemStates.Selected) == ListViewItemStates.Selected)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(overlay, bLoc);
    }
    else  {  }

    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, listView1.Font, Brushes.Black,
                bLoc.X, bLoc.Y + imgS.Height + 10);
}
```

It uses `Images` in a `64x64 ImageList` and a suitable 80x80 bitmap with a drop shadow (created in Photoshop) :

[image: aDropShadowBitmap]

To visualize the selection I overlay the image with a semitransparent `Bitmap overlay`. Here is the result:

[image: aListViewWithShadows]

**Note**: As is, the result has a subtle bug: Clicking on the texts won't select the items. The remedy is a simple workaround..:

The `ItemHeight` can't be set directly. Instead it is derived from the maximum heights of the assigned and applicable `ImageLists`: Here `LargeImageList` and `StateImageList`.

Unless we want to add extra transparent pixels to all our images, we can enlarge the active height of the items by adding a second `ImageList` with an `ImageSize  1x100` and assign it as the `StateImageList`. Ne need to add actual `Images`! Now the item texts will also select the items..!