# Create drop shadow programatically where MDI control going to drop

Tags: c#, winforms, shadow, mdi

I created snap to grid to the MDI controls so i want to calculate and draw shadow where to cntrol will locate in drop. 
For now i draw square (with Graphics()) where the inner control going to be droped but its looks bad, there is a good looking way to draw shadow programatiaclly in C# winforms? or any opensource control that can do something like that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand just what you want to do; have a look at these post, though: [shadow 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218347/how-to-draw-a-drop-shadow-on-ellipse/29227385?s=1|2.9474#29227385) and [shadow 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513233/how-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-a-listview/28531625?s=2|2.2382#28531625)

Comment: i want to draw squared shadow where the inner form going to be droped (like dragging icon in the desktop to a new place and the icon can be droped in specific place because the screen divided to invisible grid)

Comment: Can you explain what "looks bad" means? Have you tried drawing a rectangle with for instance `Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)` (semi-transparent black color)?